# ID received from post - send via ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, jquery-waypoints, getvalue

I would like to read the post id from html and send it via AJAX to the controller. How can I get the post ID (`$post->id`) and transfer it via AJAX? Or is there a better solution to save the post seen by the user?

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div id="post_container_{{$post->id}}" class="row waypoint">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This is my AJAX code:

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/posts/view',
            type: "post",
            data:
            success: function(request){
                console.log(request);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            headers:{
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    }, {
        offset: '100%'
});
```

Comment: you just simply need to send the `$post->id` to the server, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the id from the focused waypoint.

```
let waypoint_id = this.getAttribute('id'); // something like 'post_container_1'
```

Get only the string after the `_`

```
let post_id = waypoint_id.split("_").pop(); // something like '1'
```

in `ajax()` function

```
data: {
    post_id: post_id
}
```

Comment: I have to load the post id directly from the post, because i load more than one post via foreach into the view.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i get a error message: Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: i get the follow:`t {key: "waypoint-0", options: {…}, element: div#post_container_24.row.waypoint, adapter: t, callback: ƒ, …}
adapter: t {$element: n.fn.init(1)}
axis: "vertical"
callback: ƒ ()
context: e {element: Window, Adapter: ƒ, adapter: t, key: "waypoint-context-0", didScroll: false, …}
element: div#post_container_24.row.waypoint
enabled: true
group: i {name: "default", axis: "vertical", id: "default-vertical", waypoints: Array(15), triggerQueues: {…}}
key: "waypoint-0"
options: {context: Window, continuous: true, enabled: true, group: "default", ....`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `data-id` attribute like so:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div id="post_container_{{$post->id}}" data-id="{{$post->id}}" class="row waypoint">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And then access it using the `attr()`

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    let post_id = $(this).attr('data-id');   //this specifies the particular post row in focus.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/view',
        type: "post",
        data: {post_id: post_id}
        //and so on. 
    });
}, {
offset: '100%'
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i get a error message: this.attr is not a function